# joining two table in sqlite

Tags: android, mysql, sql, sqlite

`i have two table` [image: table 1 data]
`and table two data is`[image: table 2]

```
and i want to show just like this
```

[image: table 3]

I have to make a table out of two other tables one table with column  `word` and `serial` and another with column `meaning`
 and `serial`.

Now what I have to do is put this result(data) 
into `table3` (a table i already have, with the same columns as in table1 and (table2) tried lots but can't please help me
            I hope this isn't too confusing of a question.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question. I guess you know how to get the desired results, as this is *very* basic SQL. So your question is how to insert these result records in a table? And what has MySQL to do with your question?

Comment: BTW: Rather than posting pictures, you should show data as text. That's easier to read. You should also always show your own effort (i.e. query), so we see were you got stuck.

Comment: I guess your question is regarding insertion of records in the third table, put some sample code which you have tried. We might be able to help you better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select
  a.serial,
  b.word,
  a.word as meaning
from  tbl1 a
join tbl2 b on a.serial = b.serial
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the sql query your looking for ,details related to the same is been provided in the link below

```
INSERT INTO table3 (serial,word,meaning)
SELECT t1.serial,t2.word,t1.word 
FROM table1 as t1 
JOIN table2 as t2 ON t1.serial=t2.serial
```

click here [w3schools SQL tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
select * from eng join other on eng.serial=other.serial
```